# Using make_caption of koyha-ss encountered an RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, caption

I Use the command as follows

```
./venv/Scripts/python.exe "finetune/make_captions.py" --batch_size="1" --num_beams="2" --top_p="0.9" --max_length="200" --min_length="10" --beam_search --caption_extension=".txt" "D:\caption" --caption_weights="D:\kohya_ss\models\model_large_caption.pth"
```

There are only 200 image files in D:\caption

The detailed error message cannot be sent out, the platform will display too much code and too little text...

The num bleams can be adjusted to 1 to run, but I want to know why it cannot run when it is greater than 1, and I have not found relevant documents.